# Saving vectorizer in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, tokenize

I have one doubt about saving vectorizer for later use in production:

a) does fitting (in this case with vocabulary and all other params set) changes its parameters ?

b) does fitting (in general) changes vectorizer parameters ?

c) does it matter when it is - saved before of after fitting (that depend if it is changed during fitting)?

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 2), lowercase=True, stop_words=StopWordsList, token_pattern=r'\b\w{3,}\b', norm='l1', sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.99, min_df=0.01,  max_features=10000, vocabulary=FreqDict1000)


VectFName = PathName + 'VECTORIZER/' + SysName + 'vec.pkl'
joblib.dump(vec, VectFName)
```

I compared vec.get_params before and after it seems that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the vocabulary_ property or get_feature_names(), not vec.get_params. From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit) by fitting TfidfVectorizer you are changing its vocabulary and idf_ frequencies. This is the whole point of fitting.